# Link between Lagrange Multipliers in Quantum Optimal Control and Traditional Method

Tags: textbook-and-exercises, quantum-control

In the context of quantum optimal control, the term "Lagrange multiplier" has been used, which seems to draw a connection to the traditional Lagrange multiplier method used in problems of maximizing and minimizing functions of multiple variables. I would like to gain a deeper understanding of the relationship between Lagrange multipliers in quantum optimal control and their counterparts in the traditional Lagrange multiplier method. Is there a direct association between these two concepts? If so, how are they related? It would be helpful to provide examples or references that can clarify this connection.